# Reusing object in the model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I have a **Ticket** model.

I have these custom methods in this model:

```
public static function listing()
{
    $query = self::with('user', 'group', 'category', 'replies', 'club.country', 'club.membership.package', 'club.product');

    return $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->paginate(20);
}

public static function total()
{
    return self::query()->count();
}

public static function open()
{
    return self::query()->where('status', '!=', 2)->count();
}

public static function search($search)
{
    $query = self::with('user', 'group', 'category', 'replies', 'club.country', 'club.membership.package', 'club.product');

    $query->where('subject', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%');

    return $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
}
```

When I use at the same time `listing()` or `search()` + `total()` and `open()` I believe it will be returned 3 objects.

So I wonder is it possible to inject/made availabe everywhere in the model the object returned by `self::query()`?

Now instead of calling/invoking `self::query()` or `self::with()` within all these custom methods I could instead refer to an existing object.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: I don't want to recreate an object everytime I do `self::query()`, that's all.

Comment: I asked what you want it for, not what you don't want to do.

Comment: Please see my update Mr. deczo, I may be getting this wrong.

Comment: Yes, I see the update, but you still don't say what you need this for. There will be a way to do that for sure, but tell me what you want to do with that data, use case. Why you define static methods for this for example? Is it that you want to refer to the total number of users if it's User model for example? If that's the case why you would like a private prop..? I'm guessing, so elaborate on this

Comment: Ok, I have tried again.

Answer (score 1):

What your asking for seems to be [scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes).

```
<?php
class Model extends Eloquent {
    public function scopeTotal($query) {
        return $query->count();
    }

    public function scopeOpen($query) {
        return $query->where('status', 1);
    }
}
```

And then use it like `Model::open()->get()` to get all rows with `status` set to `1`, or `Model::open()->total()` to count number of rows where `status` equals to `1` .

Comment: It's better to return the `$query` so method chaining is posible.

Comment: I appreciate your answer Marwelln, but I'm not looking for scopes.